# rosdep install -ay fails on voyage linux/debian squeeze

Tags: ros, installation, rosdep, packages, debian

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi there!

I am trying to install ROS on an ALIX board running Voyage Linux 0.8.5 which is based on Debian Squeeze. I followed the experimental guide for installing ROS Fuerte on Debian. Things are working fine until I perform step 1.5 entering

rosdep install -ay --os="debian:squeeze"

I found some suggestions on how to fix the problem, but they didn't help:

http://answers.ros.org/question/40131/definition-for-ros-packages-on-debian-squeeze/ : This guy has a very similar problem, but updating the rosdep database did not change anything. However, the test works on my machine.

http://answers.ros.org/question/33002/rosdep-install-a-fails-on-debian-sqeeze/ :
Similar problem, but I am not sure what to do in my case. However, the package python-qt-bindings I am missing is not contained by the git repository. Therefore, the suggestion probably wouldnt't help anyway, right?

http://answers.ros.org/question/40081/rosdep-doesnt-recognize-os/ : I tried to manually (apt-get) install python-qt-bindings and pcl (or their equivalents for Debian Squeeze in the repositories). It doesn't work but it could be caused by the fact that the equivalent Debian packages do not have the same names, so ROS/rosdep does not detect them. However, this is just guess.

I am really confused and I really need some help to ROS running. Finally, this is the output after performing rosdep install -ay --os="debian:squeeze":

```
Executing script below with cwd=/tmp
{{{
#!/bin/bash
export PREFIX=/usr/
[ f932cebad87302d8ea0ec1fd39b24d99 = `cat $PREFIX/include/eigen3/eigen-version.installed` ]

}}}

cat: /usr//include/eigen3/eigen-version.installed: No such file or directory
/tmp/tmpeRgUII: line 3: [: f932cebad87302d8ea0ec1fd39b24d99: unary operator expected
Executing script below with cwd=/tmp
{{{
#!/bin/bash
set -o errexit
dpkg-query -W -f='${Package} ${Status}\n' yaml-cpp-sourcedep 2>&1 | awk '{\
if ($4 =="installed") 
  exit 0
else
  print "yaml-cpp-sourcedep not installed"
  exit 1}'

}}}

yaml-cpp-sourcedep not installed
Executing script below with cwd=/tmp
{{{
#!/bin/bash
export PREFIX=/usr/
if [ -f $PREFIX/include/assimp/assimp-version.installed ]; then
  [ 2ed0b9954bcb2572c0dade8f849b9260 = `cat $PREFIX/include/assimp/assimp-version.installed` ]
else
  false
fi

}}}

ERROR: the following packages/stacks could not have their rosdep keys resolved
to system dependencies:
python_qt_binding: No definition of [ros] for OS [debian]
rviz: No definition of [python-qt-bindings] for OS [debian]
runtime_monitor: Missing resource rxbag
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/root/ros/diagnostics
ROS path [2]=/root/ros/common
ROS path [3]=/root/ros/laser_pipeline
ROS path [4]=/root/ros/executive_smach_visualization
ROS path [5]=/root/ros/visualization_tutorials
ROS path [6]=/root/ros/geometry
ROS path [7]=/root/ros/pluginlib
ROS path [8]=/root/ros/bullet
ROS path [9]=/root/ros/robot_model
ROS path [10]=/root/ros/xacro
ROS path [11]=/root/ros/dynamic_reconfigure
ROS path [12]=/root/ros/executive_smach
ROS path [13]=/root/ros/driver_common
ROS path [14]=/root/ros/visualization_common
ROS path [15]=/root/ros/python_qt_binding
ROS path [16]=/root/ros/bond_core
ROS path [17]=/root/ros/image_common
ROS path [18]=/root/ros/geometry_visualization
ROS path [19]=/root/ros/common_rosdeps
ROS path [20]=/root/ros/diagnostics_monitors
ROS path [21]=/root/ros/bfl
ROS path [22]=/root/ros/common_tutorials
ROS path [23]=/root/ros/robot_model_visualization
ROS path [24]=/root/ros/geometry_experimental
ROS path [25]=/root/ros/perception_pcl
ROS path [26]=/root/ros/visualization
ROS path [27]=/root/ros/robot_model_tutorials
ROS path [28]=/root/ros/filters
ROS path [29]=/root/ros/orocos_kinematics_dynamics
ROS path [30]=/root/ros/geometry_tutorials
ROS path [31]=/root/ros/nodelet_core
ROS path [32]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [33]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [34]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
turtle_actionlib: Missing resource turtlesim
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/root/ros/diagnostics
ROS path [2]=/root/ros/common
ROS path [3]=/root/ros/laser_pipeline
ROS path [4]=/root/ros/executive_smach_visualization
ROS path [5]=/root/ros/visualization_tutorials
ROS path [6]=/root/ros/geometry
ROS path [7]=/root/ros/pluginlib
ROS path [8]=/root/ros/bullet
ROS path [9]=/root/ros/robot_model
ROS path [10]=/root/ros/xacro
ROS path [11]=/root/ros/dynamic_reconfigure
ROS path [12]=/root/ros/executive_smach
ROS path [13]=/root/ros/driver_common
ROS path [14]=/root/ros/visualization_common
ROS path [15]=/root/ros/python_qt_binding
ROS path [16]=/root/ros/bond_core
ROS path [17]=/root/ros/image_common
ROS path [18]=/root/ros/geometry_visualization
ROS path [19]=/root/ros/common_rosdeps
ROS path [20]=/root/ros/diagnostics_monitors
ROS path [21]=/root/ros/bfl
ROS path [22]=/root/ros/common_tutorials
ROS path [23]=/root/ros/robot_model_visualization
ROS path [24]=/root/ros/geometry_experimental
ROS path [25]=/root/ros/perception_pcl
ROS path [26]=/root/ros/visualization
ROS path [27]=/root/ros/robot_model_tutorials
ROS path [28]=/root/ros/filters
ROS path [29]=/root/ros/orocos_kinematics_dynamics
ROS path [30]=/root/ros/geometry_tutorials
ROS path [31]=/root/ros/nodelet_core
ROS path [32]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [33]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [34]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
smach_viewer: Missing resource xdot
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/root/ros/diagnostics
ROS path [2]=/root/ros/common
ROS path [3]=/root/ros/laser_pipeline
ROS path [4]=/root/ros/executive_smach_visualization
ROS path [5]=/root/ros/visualization_tutorials
ROS path [6]=/root/ros/geometry
ROS path [7]=/root/ros/pluginlib
ROS path [8]=/root/ros/bullet
ROS path [9]=/root/ros/robot_model
ROS path [10]=/root/ros/xacro
ROS path [11]=/root/ros/dynamic_reconfigure
ROS path [12]=/root/ros/executive_smach
ROS path [13]=/root/ros/driver_common
ROS path [14]=/root/ros/visualization_common
ROS path [15]=/root/ros/python_qt_binding
ROS path [16]=/root/ros/bond_core
ROS path [17]=/root/ros/image_common
ROS path [18]=/root/ros/geometry_visualization
ROS path [19]=/root/ros/common_rosdeps
ROS path [20]=/root/ros/diagnostics_monitors
ROS path [21]=/root/ros/bfl
ROS path [22]=/root/ros/common_tutorials
ROS path [23]=/root/ros/robot_model_visualization
ROS path [24]=/root/ros/geometry_experimental
ROS path [25]=/root/ros/perception_pcl
ROS path [26]=/root/ros/visualization
ROS path [27]=/root/ros/robot_model_tutorials
ROS path [28]=/root/ros/filters
ROS path [29]=/root/ros/orocos_kinematics_dynamics
ROS path [30]=/root/ros/geometry_tutorials
ROS path [31]=/root/ros/nodelet_core
ROS path [32]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [33]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [34]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
robot_monitor: Missing resource rxbag
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/root/ros/diagnostics
ROS path [2]=/root/ros/common
ROS path [3]=/root/ros/laser_pipeline
ROS path [4]=/root/ros/executive_smach_visualization
ROS path [5]=/root/ros/visualization_tutorials
ROS path [6]=/root/ros/geometry
ROS path [7]=/root/ros/pluginlib
ROS path [8]=/root/ros/bullet
ROS path [9]=/root/ros/robot_model
ROS path [10]=/root/ros/xacro
ROS path [11]=/root/ros/dynamic_reconfigure
ROS path [12]=/root/ros/executive_smach
ROS path [13]=/root/ros/driver_common
ROS path [14]=/root/ros/visualization_common
ROS path [15]=/root/ros/python_qt_binding
ROS path [16]=/root/ros/bond_core
ROS path [17]=/root/ros/image_common
ROS path [18]=/root/ros/geometry_visualization
ROS path [19]=/root/ros/common_rosdeps
ROS path [20]=/root/ros/diagnostics_monitors
ROS path [21]=/root/ros/bfl
ROS path [22]=/root/ros/common_tutorials
ROS path [23]=/root/ros/robot_model_visualization
ROS path [24]=/root/ros/geometry_experimental
ROS path [25]=/root/ros/perception_pcl
ROS path [26]=/root/ros/visualization
ROS path [27]=/root/ros/robot_model_tutorials
ROS path [28]=/root/ros/filters
ROS path [29]=/root/ros/orocos_kinematics_dynamics
ROS path [30]=/root/ros/geometry_tutorials
ROS path [31]=/root/ros/nodelet_core
ROS path [32]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [33]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [34]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
tf2_visualization: Missing resource xdot
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/root/ros/diagnostics
ROS path [2]=/root/ros/common
ROS path [3]=/root/ros/laser_pipeline
ROS path [4]=/root/ros/executive_smach_visualization
ROS path [5]=/root/ros/visualization_tutorials
ROS path [6]=/root/ros/geometry
ROS path [7]=/root/ros/pluginlib
ROS path [8]=/root/ros/bullet
ROS path [9]=/root/ros/robot_model
ROS path [10]=/root/ros/xacro
ROS path [11]=/root/ros/dynamic_reconfigure
ROS path [12]=/root/ros/executive_smach
ROS path [13]=/root/ros/driver_common
ROS path [14]=/root/ros/visualization_common
ROS path [15]=/root/ros/python_qt_binding
ROS path [16]=/root/ros/bond_core
ROS path [17]=/root/ros/image_common
ROS path [18]=/root/ros/geometry_visualization
ROS path [19]=/root/ros/common_rosdeps
ROS path [20]=/root/ros/diagnostics_monitors
ROS path [21]=/root/ros/bfl
ROS path [22]=/root/ros/common_tutorials
ROS path [23]=/root/ros/robot_model_visualization
ROS path [24]=/root/ros/geometry_experimental
ROS path [25]=/root/ros/perception_pcl
ROS path [26]=/root/ros/visualization
ROS path [27]=/root/ros/robot_model_tutorials
ROS path [28]=/root/ros/filters
ROS path [29]=/root/ros/orocos_kinematics_dynamics
ROS path [30]=/root/ros/geometry_tutorials
ROS path [31]=/root/ros/nodelet_core
ROS path [32]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [33]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [34]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
laser_filters: No definition of [pcl] for OS [debian]
turtle_tf: Missing resource turtlesim
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/root/ros/diagnostics
ROS path [2]=/root/ros/common
ROS path [3]=/root/ros/laser_pipeline
ROS path [4]=/root/ros/executive_smach_visualization
ROS path [5]=/root/ros/visualization_tutorials
ROS path [6]=/root/ros/geometry
ROS path [7]=/root/ros/pluginlib
ROS path [8]=/root/ros/bullet
ROS path [9]=/root/ros/robot_model
ROS path [10]=/root/ros/xacro
ROS path [11]=/root/ros/dynamic_reconfigure
ROS path [12]=/root/ros/executive_smach
ROS path [13]=/root/ros/driver_common
ROS path [14]=/root/ros/visualization_common
ROS path [15]=/root/ros/python_qt_binding
ROS path [16]=/root/ros/bond_core
ROS path [17]=/root/ros/image_common
ROS path [18]=/root/ros/geometry_visualization
ROS path [19]=/root/ros/common_rosdeps
ROS path [20]=/root/ros/diagnostics_monitors
ROS path [21]=/root/ros/bfl
ROS path [22]=/root/ros/common_tutorials
ROS path [23]=/root/ros/robot_model_visualization
ROS path [24]=/root/ros/geometry_experimental
ROS path [25]=/root/ros/perception_pcl
ROS path [26]=/root/ros/visualization
ROS path [27]=/root/ros/robot_model_tutorials
ROS path [28]=/root/ros/filters
ROS path [29]=/root/ros/orocos_kinematics_dynamics
ROS path [30]=/root/ros/geometry_tutorials
ROS path [31]=/root/ros/nodelet_core
ROS path [32]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [33]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [34]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
laser_assembler: No definition of [pcl] for OS [debian]
rxbag_plugins: Missing resource rxbag
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/root/ros/diagnostics
ROS path [2]=/root/ros/common
ROS path [3]=/root/ros/laser_pipeline
ROS path [4]=/root/ros/executive_smach_visualization
ROS path [5]=/root/ros/visualization_tutorials
ROS path [6]=/root/ros/geometry
ROS path [7]=/root/ros/pluginlib
ROS path [8]=/root/ros/bullet
ROS path [9]=/root/ros/robot_model
ROS path [10]=/root/ros/xacro
ROS path [11]=/root/ros/dynamic_reconfigure
ROS path [12]=/root/ros/executive_smach
ROS path [13]=/root/ros/driver_common
ROS path [14]=/root/ros/visualization_common
ROS path [15]=/root/ros/python_qt_binding
ROS path [16]=/root/ros/bond_core
ROS path [17]=/root/ros/image_common
ROS path [18]=/root/ros/geometry_visualization
ROS path [19]=/root/ros/common_rosdeps
ROS path [20]=/root/ros/diagnostics_monitors
ROS path [21]=/root/ros/bfl
ROS path [22]=/root/ros/common_tutorials
ROS path [23]=/root/ros/robot_model_visualization
ROS path [24]=/root/ros/geometry_experimental
ROS path [25]=/root/ros/perception_pcl
ROS path [26]=/root/ros/visualization
ROS path [27]=/root/ros/robot_model_tutorials
ROS path [28]=/root/ros/filters
ROS path [29]=/root/ros/orocos_kinematics_dynamics
ROS path [30]=/root/ros/geometry_tutorials
ROS path [31]=/root/ros/nodelet_core
ROS path [32]=/opt/ros/fuerte/stacks
ROS path [33]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share
ROS path [34]=/opt/ros/fuerte/share/ros
librviz_tutorial: No definition of [python-qt-bindings] for OS [debian]
rviz_plugin_tutorials: No definition of [python-qt-bindings] for OS [debian]
pcl_ros: No definition of [pcl] for OS [debian]
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/42724/rosdep-install--ay-fails-on-voyage-linux/debian-squeeze/) by [brhempen](https://answers.ros.org/users/3117/brhempen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2012-08-31

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

No one has yet defined any [`rosdep` rules for `python-qt-bindings`](https://github.com/ros/rosdistro/blob/master/rosdep/python.yaml) in Debian Squeeze.

You can define them and contribute back to the community by following [these directions](http://ros.org/doc/api/rosdep2/html/contributing_rules.html).

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-08-31

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-08-31**:
One of the Ubuntu stanzas may possibly work for Squeeze. You can experiment with them.